# React native scroll over interactive content

Tags: react-native

I watched this presentation and there's a section on how to [build an IOS Maps](https://youtu.be/V8maYc4R2G0?t=13m45s) like UI. When dragging from the bottom to top, it drags to the top, and after it reaches the top, it continues scrolling up. Also, when scrolling down, when it reached the top content of the ScrollView, it continues to drag down.

It is suggested that it can be done using ScrollView by adding an empty transparent cell as the first element on the ScrollView. I have tried implementing the same which can be found in this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kakarn/scrollview---handler). In my case, instead of Maps, I am using another ScrollView.

But the problem is that the first element (transparent element) does not allow to interact with the First ScrollView elements. I have tried with pointerEvents inside the first transparent view and even in its parent ScrollView. But this does not help. Has anyone tried implementing this kind of use case with react-native? All I found was [this library](https://github.com/rome2rio/react-native-touch-through-view), but I think it's not maintained properly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the z-index of the transparent view to send it under/behind the interactive content, here is a good resource:

https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

**Edit**: Actually I could not accomplish it, it seems like everything inside a scrollview will always be behind or in front of other elements, it seems like you can't have part of the scrollview behind something else and another part in front of something else.